# How does CLR call finalize on an object if it knows that no root to that object exists?

Tags: c#

I am reading CLR Via C# and on the garbage collection topic it is mentioned that the objects that have a finalize method are added to another list.

If no root exists to this particular object then how can the finalize of that object be called?

Have I understood something wrong. Please explain this particular gap/link/detail if possible?

Comment: Scan, Mark and Sweep on a particular interval.

Comment: That I understand but if the object can not be accessed then how can its finalize be called? This is the question.

Comment: Objects with a finalize method are added to the finalization queue on construction and then moved to the f-reachable queue when they are GC'd.

Comment: @Lee: Yes i definitely understand that but the object is marked for finalization because it is no longer considered valid. Then how can CLR call a finalize on that object. This is my question.

Comment: @ckv - It's not considered valid because there are no roots on the managed heap, but the GC still has a reference to the object in the finalization queue. It moves it into the f-reachable queue and then calls finalize when it next empties that.

Comment: On the bottom of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) there is a good explanation of finalizable objects and how the CLR handles them.

Answer (score 1):

.NET is a memory managed platform. It knows of each and every one of your objects, even if there are no roots in the memory (heap, stack, etc.) of the application.

It is documented in many places, this is one of my favorites: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx